# Push data to dataLayer and send it to Google Analytics at the same time in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer, enhanced-ecommerce

I have a complicated issue with GTM, dataLayer and GA.

My setup is:

- GA tag is triggered in PageView with Enhanced Ecommerce enabled by using dataLayer
- A Custom HTML tag which pushes an item to dataLayer, and it's configured to run just before the GA tag (by using tag sequencing)

Problem is; GA is not including dataLayer changes made by custom Tag even if it's fired after Custom tag.

I noticed, **dataLayer.push(...)** creates a new GTM event named message.

How can I handle this, GA pageview tag must have the final dataLayer.

tHanks

Answer (score 1):

The datalayer is not re-evaluated in a tag sequence. However you can manipulate the dataLayer directly.

First you need to make sure that the built-in "Container ID" variable is active (or you pass in the ID manually).

Then you get a reference to your GTM instance and call a dataLayer.set with a key and value:

```
var gtm = google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}];
gtm.dataLayer.set('someKey',"someValue")
```

Unlike a dataLayer.push this will be available in the next step in the sequence.

Comment: Hi Eike; Thanks your fast reply, I just tried it. I added the code to Custom Html tag which runs before GA Tag in pageview event.Code changed the dataLayer but not in pageview event, in dom ready event.

Comment: Hi again; I fixed the domReady event problem I described in my previous comment. Now dataLayer change is seen in the pageview event, but GA request still doesnot have the values changed in dataLayer. :(